# VS2013 Express not Compiling as normal

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-express

Just having an annoying issue with VS not compiling correctly and showing a bogus compile error.

```
Error   1   'ConcurUtility' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.    <path>\App_Code\AppUtility.vb   22  34  KWAI
Error   2   'T' is not a member of 'System.Text.StringBuilder'. <path>\App_Code\AppUtility.vb   30  16  KWAI
```

It says my class is not declared when it clearly is as it comes up in intelli-sense. It is declared public and my method I am calling is

```
Pubic Shared Function GetDocument(...
```

I have commented out my call to the function and it does compile then so it cannot be the ConcurUtility class that is causing the issue.

I have rebooted my machine and it is still not working. I have cleaned and tried to rebuild but to no avail. Any ideas what is causing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should troubleshoot your second error instead. I guess ConcurUtility was not public in the last successful build, and VS is still considering it as protected/internal based on that.

Comment: Always been public

Comment: The error message may be misleading sometimes, if possible may you post part of the source code where the compiler is complaining?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Project File must have been corrupt (who knows) as I started from scratch and added every class in manually then copied and pasted my code from my old project to the new one and it works fine. Just one of those things that perhaps the express version must have a unknown bug because it is hard to reproduce. I.e. the clean does not really do a thorough clean.

The only thing I can recall is I created the class under a different name and renamed the call before renaming the class and file and somehow this has been cached and so it no longer complies. Not worth my effort figuring it out. Tis one of those unsolved mysteries.